# combine dataframes in pandas with repeat slices of one of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine 2 dataframes.

Here are the samples of dataframes:

df1:

[linktoDF1](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5DfuTWg1OMjfUvzT9DN5XQQ5WW3A?e=vgDJid)

[image]

df2:

[linkdoDF2](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5DfuTWg1OMjfUw7qnFKj7Eel6siA?e=y8f3Fv)

[image]

Desired output should be:

[linktoResultcsv](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5DfuTWg1OMjfUxq0tkSvUJ2A-k5w?e=qKyR1P)

[image]

What I want in essence is to extend df1 with data from df2. Key to linking data is index of both dataframes which is `['latitude','level','longitude']`. I want to omit data with index unique to df2. i.e. I don't want to see data with index `[41, 1000, 19.25 ]`
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "merge" with how='left', which omits indexes not in df1:

```
rslt= pd.merge(df1,df2,on=["latitude","level","longitude"],how="left")
```

Comment: I get error `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat` with `dtypes` command, I see all data as `float32`

Comment: Figured out, `index` level was converted to `object`. Thanks.